# I use #if in Svlte Native but it doesn't work

Tags: nativescript, svelte, svelte-native

I try out [Svelte Native](https://svelte-native.technology/) and I try to hide "tags" with booleans. I try this, which works in the normal Svelte framework like:

```
{#if po.id !== null || po.id !== undefined}
        <flexboxLayout flexWrap="wrap" class="v-a-c t-a-c" >
            <label text="first" width="70%" backgroundColor="#63c3d0" class="m6"></label>
            <label text="second" width="70%" backgroundColor="#63c3d0" class="m6"></label>
            <label text="third" width="70%" backgroundColor="#63c3d0" class="m6"></label>
        </flexboxLayout>
    {:else }
        <stackLayout flexWrap="wrap" class="v-a-c t-a-c">
            <textField  bind:text="{personName}" class="m6 new-person" ></textField>
            <button text="add new value" on:tap="{createNewPlayer}" />
        </stackLayout>
    {/if}
```

So why it doesn't work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need further details. Do you get an error in the console? Which tag is showing, the `IF` or the `ELSE`? Where is your `po` set?

I also recommend to check for `po.id !== undefined` first! If it is undefiened, this will run into an error. The correct way would be `{#if po.id !== undefined && po.id !== null}`

Comment: i get no error in the console. 
`let po: person = new person()
    let id
    let newPerson: boolean = true

    onMount(async () => {
        id = getNumber("id")
        console.log(id)
        if (id !== null && id !== undefined) {
            newPlayer = false
            getPlayerOverviewData()
        } else {
            // show empty side and create new player
            newPerson = true
        }

    });`

Comment: here i initialize it